# SSO using multiple FederationID values

Tags: single-sign-on, federated-authentication

My client has asked to configure SSO using FederationID.
When client login to the other application, they use either EmpID, userName, emailaddress for authenticating.

My issue is when client tries to log in to the salesforce, it expects only one value to enter while authentication. Client wants to login to the salesforce SSO using any value either EmpID, userName, emailaddress.

Comment: Take a look at [Login Discovery](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_login_discovery_create_discovery.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You can only use one value for the Federated ID. The login ID that was provided to the authentication server does not need to be the ID that is presented to Salesforce. Most systems have a concept of a UUID or GUID that identifies the user logging in uniquely, no matter which login method they use.

The trick here is that you simply need to configure that server to provide the correct unique identifier regardless of which method the user uses to log in. For example, if my work allowed me to log in by phone number, email, or employee ID, my Principal Name would still map to something like `enterprise-domain\firstname-lastname`, and that is how Salesforce would identify my user account.